# How to throw an exception if something wrong with tagHelper in asp.net core mvc

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

TagHelpers is a nice thing, but they are absolutely silent an it's hard to identify that something goes wrong with them. For example if there is a typo in path like that `<script asp-src-include="/path/that/not/exist"></script>` it's not possible to find this out before you actually not check markup and see that it's rendered incorrectly. Is it possible to force default tagHelpers throw an exception when something is wrong during the rendering?

Comment: How would you do that, in most deployment scenarios the files aren't bundled/copied/created in wwwroot until you build or publish it

Comment: I think for different deployment scenarios there is different `<environments>` tags.

Comment: Yes, but the file is non-existent if it's build/bundled on publishing or during building, i.e. using [scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#scripts) section, like `<Target Name="MyPostCompileTarget" AfterTargets="Publish">` to run `npm install` or `bower install` to download the packages, so having exception there would be counter productive, i.e. it would always throw exception on `<script asp-src-inlcude"/>` tags which refer to productive versions since they are unavailable until deployment maybe

Comment: There is a lot of other cases which still create problems. For example if taghelper used in selfclosed tag, which isn't allowed to be selfclosed. It's once again just silently fail. If something not work - it should not goes silent